# SQL Server generate consecutive Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following Situation.
I need to query Data to initial insert them into my Database. In a second step, I need to append Data to the new Table.

The challenge is that all Data does not have a primary key - so I need to generate one. That needs to be the Document-No in the Data and the new created Line-No.

Every statement needs to begin with SELECT.

Example Data:

```
Initial Data:

DocumentNo | Name | Surname |
---------------------------------
1111 | Smith | John |
2222 | Muller | Edwin |
3333 | Schulz | Jack |
1111 | Smith | John |
2222 | Muller | Edwin |
```

Data to Add on daily basis:

```
DocumentNo | Name | Surname |
---------------------------------
1111 | Smith | John |
4444 | Baker | Terry |
5555 | Wall | Katrin |


Desired final Table:

LineNo | DocumentNo | Name | Surname | ID
---------------------------------
1 | 1111 | Smith | John |
2 | 2222 | Muller | Edwin |
3 | 3333 | Schulz | Jack |
4 | 1111 | Smith | John |
5 | 2222 | Muller | Edwin |
6 | 1111 | Smith | John |
7 | 4444 | Baker | Terry |
8 | 5555 | Wall | Katrin |
```

With this final table, I have a primary key by the combination of LineNo and DocumentNo and I am able to append Data.

I really have no idea where to start and every hint is appreciated. It is possible to create additional tables to store data if necessary (the create table statement should not be part of the statement though)

Comment: You should use autoincrement.
Read more there:
http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-auto-increment.htm

Comment: What you mean by _the Document-No in the Data and the new created Line-No_ is it 1112 or 1111-1? You did not provide how the ID should be.

Comment: Is it your school project?

Comment: @Sami it does not really matter how they look like. I just need a chance to always add new Data without a key to an existing table.

Answer (score 0):

For your final table you can use the **IDENTITY** function on the LineNo column. This will auto increment the number each time data is inserted into the table.

The below script will create the final table in your question but will set up the LineNo column to start at number 1 and auto increment by 1 each time an insert is done.

```
create table finalTable (
    lineNo int not null identity(1,1)
    ,documentNo int not null
    ,name nvarchar(max) not null
    ,surname nvarchar(max) not null
    ,id int not null
);

alter table finalTable
add constraint [pk_finalTable_lineNo] primary key (lineNo);
```

You can now perform the INSERT...SELECT statement to append data into the table without getting a primary key clash.

Let me know if that is not what you were looking for.

Comment: thx for your input. Unfortunatly, this will not work in my environment. Is there another way than the identify funtion to add consecutive Numbers?

Comment: Providing that you have SQL Server 2012 or above, you could use the CREATE SEQUENCE statement to increment the number. You can use this link to read about it     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql